# For docplex, it's possible to set the number of iterations without improvement?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, docplex

When running the cplex model, I noticed that the CPLEX repeats the same gap value several times. I ask if there is a parameter in docplex that limits the number of iterations without improvements or just stop it after obtaining n times the same value on the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the relevant manuals. I am not aware of any such functionality and a search of named parameters in the documentation yields no results either.

However this [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.7.1.0?topic=cpxxgetcallbackinfo-cpxgetcallbackinfo) goes into details how to get the information you want and also documents in an example how to stop it from this callback based on this information using the C Interface.

Comment: The question is tagged docplex, which is the interface being used. Essentially, it's Python.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know and edited my answer.

Comment: To expand on this answer: No, this cannot be done by a parameter. You would need to attach a callback (a node callback would work). In the callback, you would need to get the MIP gap (for which there is a function), compare it to previous gaps (acquired the same way), and if there were no change for too long stop the solver (using the abort function). There seems to be a way to use callbacks from DOCplex ("cb_mixin module"), about which I know nothing.

Comment: Thank you, I figure out how to stop the solver depending on the gap using a callback function but it's not what I really needed, I am looking for a way to direct the search like changing the search space without stopping the solver?

Comment: @Nada.M Based on the comments above and the fact you have tried something yourself and looking for something different, I would suggest that you edit your question and add this additional information.